# How to get packages to import in code within anaconda virtualenv?

Tags: python

Currently I cannot import package installed in virtual environment:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/glada/GIT_REPOS/autoflux/main.py", line 5, in 
import cx_oracle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_oracle'

Answer (score 0):

Imports in python are sometimes a bit tricky because it depends on *how* you call a line of code. Do you call the import from the python REPL input?

`>>> import cx_oracle`

Do you call the line of code from inside a script?

`$ python myscript.py`

Do you run the script as a module?

`$ python -m myscript`

Also a folder structure would be helpful. Do you use `virtualenv`? Maybe you have installed the package to the wrong location (installed in main python installation site-packages and now you are trying to import inside an activated virtualenv)?

There is a [brilliant answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/6453106), which is really descriptive and once I also found very useful to understand imports in python. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: I use virtualenv (installed from pip) and I try to run problematic script in VS Code. It works sometimes when I run script from terminal (like python main.py). The shebang is set to use python interpreter from virtualen vironment